# Problem inserting a column and cell reference/link

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, links

I have a sort of summary in my Google sheet.
In the second column, I refer to the sub tables further in the sheet with e.g. this content:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-
lBYHVVGjX1e8e_ZpeiNJIywJxfSW9waliWbJ2ICmM/edit#gid=0&range=f1
```

Meaning it refers to column F1.

This works fine;  when clicking on the cell in the summary the focus is moved to column F1.

However, when I insert columns before the F column, the link is not changed and thus the column is referring to the wrong column.

Is there a better way to handle this?

The link to the Google sheet is: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-lBYHVVGjX1e8e_ZpeiNJIywJxfSW9waliWbJ2ICmM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 of couirse, I added it at the end of my question.

Comment: you need to add `="` in front of it. see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need to refer it as an active range like this:

```
="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J-lBYHVVGjX1e8e_ZpeiNJIywJxfSW9waliWbJ2ICmM/edit#gid=0&range="&
 ADDRESS(ROW(D1); COLUMN(D1); 4)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, this works (slightly cumbersome to have to have a duplicate in Row and Column but inserting/deletion etc works... Thanks!

Comment: @MichelKeijzers you can drop `ROW(D1)` and put there `1`

Comment: Thanks .. works perfectly ... also I changed 1 to $1 in the column, so I always go to the first column (easier when copying the links until row 12 in my example, only have to change the column name/number, Thanks!